# sles12 - Why are core dumps not being generated for systemd services?

Tags: systemd, sles, core-dump

There is an issue that I am seeing on a sles12 env with creation of core dumps for system services (like the below java app). Need some help in understanding sles12 core dump creation process.

My goal is to set a single configuration for `ulimit` which applies to all processes (user started, systemd started or anything else). Can it be achieved?

Conditions:
1. We were expecting all processes to create dumps by default due to following configuration: the file **/etc/security/limits.conf** is already configured generally for all processes to use **ulimit** to `unlimited`).
2. My app is a java jar which is being instantiated by systemd.

Comment: Are you aware of systemd-coredump / coredumpctl? systemd-coredump accepts core dumps, saves them in its own directory instead.

Comment: Yes - I'm aware. I want to understand 'why' /etc/security/limits.conf does not affect the systemd services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Fedora system, `man limits.conf` says that it affects user sessions only.  It is applied using the PAM module `pam_limits`.

The default ulimits across all systemd units can be set in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, e.g. `DefaultLimitCORE=`.  See `man systemd-system.conf`.  If no value is specified, the default inherited from the kernel is used.

This is also mentioned in `man systemd.exec`, which discusses setting ulimits for specific systemd services.